# XCreateImage expected char* instead of unsigned int*

Tags: c, bitmap, x11

I'm using XCreateImage with a bitmap of depth of 24 bits, the bitmap is stored into an unsigned int array:

```
buffer = malloc(width*height*sizeof(unsigned int));
```

Then I create and XImage like this:

```
XImage* image = XCreateImage(display, DefaultVisual(display, 0), 24, ZPixmap, 0, buffer, width, height, 32, 0);
```

It's working, however I get this warning when compiling:

```
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:1441:16: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned int *’
extern XImage *XCreateImage(
```

Can I just cast the buffer to a char* without any problem?

Comment: The function declaration uses `char *` for historical reasons. You can use a cast.

Answer (score 1):

According to `XCreateImage(3)` the function definition is

```
   XImage *XCreateImage(Display *display, Visual *visual, unsigned int depth,  int  for‐
          mat, int offset, char *data, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, int bit‐
          map_pad, int bytes_per_line);
```

`buffer` is of type `int *` so you should cast it to `char *` like this

```
XImage* image = XCreateImage(display, DefaultVisual(display, 0), 24, ZPixmap, 0, (char *)buffer, width, height, 32, 0);
```